# Changing login/register model in asp.net mvc internet application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am starting with a new mvc5 application. When I try to register, there are some restrictions (minimum length has to be 6, alpha numeric password, etc) how do I remove those restrictions. I cannot find what to change in the account model. Is there somewhere else I have to look?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, it is in the IdentityConfig.cs, these values are what put the restrictions.

```
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 4,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
```